# how to display text below the respective image when it is clicked with out changing the position of the images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have images displayed beside each other, when I click on a particular image, its description should appear below with out changing other images' position. The code I have is this:

```
<div class="team">
  <h3>OUR TEAM</h3>
  <div class="toggle" style="display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/gallery/I7kTE" width="20" height="15"/></a> 
    <h4>name1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Img 1 description texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
  </div>
  <div class="toggle" style="display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#"><img  src="http://imgur.com/gallery/I7kTE" width="20" height="15"/></a> 
    <h4>name2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Img 2 description texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
  </div>
  <div class="toggle" style="display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/gallery/I7kTE" width="20" height="15"/></a> 
    <h4>name3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Img 3 description text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     var $content = $(".content").hide();
     $(".toggle").on("click", function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
     });
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnhLyjb6/

Comment: on your fiddle, you are using jQuery 1.6 --- you need to use jQuery 1.7 or above when using ".on", otherwise you will need to use ".delegate()", instead of ".on" - if you are using a lower version of jQuery. Once I selected a higher revision of jQuery - your code worked.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/pnhLyjb6/1/

Comment: change your js file to 1.7 or higher or use `.click(function(){....})`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I'm having one more problem. When I'm clicking an image the remaining two images are moving down when displaying the info. Is it possible to display the info with out images changing their position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/pnhLyjb6/3/)

Check above Link for Ref.... other code get from above link

**HTML**

```
  <div class="list-group">
  <a href="#section-1" id="section-1" class="list-group-item">img 1 </a>
  <a href="#section-2" id="section-2" class="list-group-item">img 2</a>
  <a href="#section-3" id="section-3" class="list-group-item">img 3</a>
  </div>

   <div class='hide section-1'>1</div>
   <div class='hide section-2'>2</div>
   <div class='hide section-3'> 3</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was struggling with $(this).next().text() to  display it some how in a new div. Your solution is more simple and precise.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your JavaScript code with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $content = $(".content").hide();
    $(".toggle").click(function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Or Use JQuery Version 1.7 or higher.

[**DEMO**](http://goo.gl/A1PTXA)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I make the other images stay in their position when displaying info when I click on an image? How can I display the info without moving the images' positions?

Comment: It is only half of what I needed. I'm clicking correct mark anyway. But if you have any idea on how to solve the problem, kindly let me  know.

Comment: The solution is keep your image & description is in separate div.

Comment: yes u Can use Switch Case . [Ref](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18160/different-way-of-writing-multiple-click-functions)

Comment: @Amy img and descripton ARE in seperate div. I don't understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @parth Akbari I have lots of images. Using switch statement makes the code longer and redundant which I don't want to do. Thank you for the input.